# Кнопка вверх android

Tags: java, android

Есть активность(активность 1), она запускает другую(активность 2), причем передает некие данные влияющие на то что отображает дочерняя активность(активность 2). Эти данные она получает из интента. В свою очередь дочерняя активность(активность 2) запускает другую активность(активность 3). В манифесте активность 3 я прописал тег android:parentName в качестве параметра указал активность 2. И теперь вот в чем проблема. Запуская из активности 1 активность 2 - все хорошо, но если запускать активность 2 из активности 3 кнопкой вверх на панели сверху слева(стрелочка) то активность 2 не получает нужные данные из-за чего не может отобразить данные и происходит ошибка. Сначала я подумал что эту проблему можно решить методами startActivityForResult() и setResult() вроде написал все правильно но что-то не выходит. Либо так не сработает либо я неправильно написал(прошу этот момент уточнить, возможно ли решить эту проблему таким образом). А потом я подумал о том что, должен быть способ переопределить событие при нажатии этой кнопки, но как я не знаю(это второй момент который прошу мне разъяснить).

Comment: Покажите код пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

C учетом замечания @pavlofff меняю ответ.

Если в третьей активности Вы используете `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar`, то по нажатию на кнопку "Вверх" следующий код вернется ко второй активности, передав ей строку:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("STRING_TO_PASS", "Some string");
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

То есть метод `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` устанавливает картинку "стрелка влево" на левой кнопке, но она по-прежнему остается кнопкой навигации, и слушатель на нее устанавливается методом  `setNavigationOnClickListener()`.

Comment: Для возврата по стеку (нажате кнопки "назад") принято использовать финиширование активити с возвратом значений через startActivityForResult(), а не забивать стек новыми активностями. Что будет в стеке, если три раза перейти с активити 2 на 3 - 7 активностей, а должно быть - 3.

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо за замечание. Исправила ответ.